# Why is StateImageIndex on TreeNode limted to a max value of 14?

Tags: winforms, treenode

Can someone here please explain to me why the [`StateImageIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.stateimageindex.aspx) on `TreeNode` is limited to a maximum value of 14? It doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: Simple: treenodes only allow 14 different states...

Comment: Dont make sence, its just an arbitrary imagelist, why is SateImageList limited when the ordinary ImageList is not. What do you mean by 14 different states?

Comment: There are three basic states: unchecked, checked or mixed. This leaves 12 more states, which fit nicely in a 4-bit variable. Possibly someone thought 13 would be unlucky or perhaps code 15 has a special meaning too.

Answer (score 2):

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775597(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773409(VS.85).aspx

The state images are referred to using a special mask, and it seems to be 4 bits in size, which makes 16 possible values and 0-14 seem to be usable.