# What is TreeNode.StateImageIndex?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.stateimageindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  . but they don't seem clear.

What is the "***state*** of the TreeNode"?

From the link:

> If the parent TreeView has check boxes enabled, the StateImageIndex is
>   ignored

and

> Toggling the Checked property does not affect the value of the
>   StateImageIndex.

So if it's supposed to indicate whether a node is checked - how can this be?

Comment: @RonBeyer How can it be checked if it's referring specifically to when checkboxes are _not_ shown? - `If the parent TreeView has check boxes enabled, the StateImageIndex is ignored` - from the link.

Comment: I read something wrong, disregard, apologies.

Comment: It still seems to be related to checkboxes, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14344/How-to-handle-custom-node-state-images-in-a-TreeVi and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760(VS.85).aspx its used for custom check/selected states it seems.

Comment: It is anything you want it to be.  I guess it would have been clearer if they called it *CustomIconIndex*.

Comment: @RonBeyer I thought you'd like to know we got an answer from the expert.

Comment: @HansPassant, if its anything you want, why is it limited to 0-14?

Comment: @RonBeyer See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471227/why-is-stateimageindex-on-treenode-limted-to-a-max-value-of-14) . (I didn't explore the answer well. But it seems to be your question.) Notice that _at least_ one comment there seems to be sarcastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments for the answer. It's anything you want.